# Save metadata as a timestamp, display as a "pretty" date

Tags: custom-post-types, events, timestamp

I have a custom meta box, its just a straight-up text field, for an event date, formatted: YYYY/MM/DD ...I'd like to save that as a date stamp (so i can sort by event date), and display just the pretty date format on the design side (ie: 2011/09/24 becomes September, 24th, 2011).

I was using this tutorial as a guide: http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/custom-post-types-events-pt1/

But I find its really hard to follow, and probably too complicated for what I'm doing.

So far I have this:

```
function event_date(){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$event_date = $custom["event_date"][0];

// - grab wp time format -
$date_format = get_option('date_format'); ?>

<label>Event Date (YYYY/MM/DD):</label>
<input name="event_date" value="<?php echo $event_date; ?>" />

  <?php
}
```

Which works in spitting out: 2011/09/25. I've been trying to figure out what to do with that $date_format bit, any ideas what I'm missing to get 2011/09/25 display as September 25, 2011 on the front end?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to store it as a timestamp to order by date, yyyy/mm/dd will work just fine.

As for converting the format:

```
$date = '2011/09/19';
$date = strtotime( $date );
echo date( 'F j, Y', $date );
```

see php's [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

EDIT- oh, maybe I misunderstood, thought you said timestamp, not date. anyway, the conversion code in the second part is what you need. a unix timestamp is the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970.